# Connect to azure-blob through azure-website with php

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I have set up an windows azure website (php), and I want to connect to the azure storage (blob) environment. I walked through the [How to use the Blob service from PHP](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/) tutorial, but that only mentions the case when the website is stored localy.

I tried to set up a few cases, but i'm constantly getting a http 500 error.

```
<?php
require_once 'WindowsAzure/WindowsAzure.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;   

//$connectionString = "\WindowsAzure\Blob\Internal\IBlob";

// Create blob REST proxy.
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString); // the code gets stuck at this line, result is a HTTP 500 error

$content = fopen("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample%20Pictures\Woestijn.jpg", "r");
$blob_name = "newBlob";


try {
    //Upload blob
    $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("default", $blob_name, $content);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here: 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}?>
```

Is there anyone who had a similar problem and managed to figure it out?

EDIT:

I now narrowed down the error search. I went into the ServicesBuilder.php file, and commented out line by line, until the page stopped to work. The line it went wrong at is **$httpClient**, as shown below:

```
public function createBlobService($connectionString)
{
    $settings = StorageServiceSettings::createFromConnectionString(
        $connectionString
    );

    $httpClient    = $this->httpClient();
    $serializer    = $this->serializer();
    $uri           = Utilities::tryAddUrlScheme(
        $settings->getBlobEndpointUri()
    );
```

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.

Comment: why is your `$connectionString` variable commented out? Also, check what Sandrino suggests.

Comment: connectionString is commented out because what I did there didn't work :). The connectionString Sandrino suggests looks like what I need, but still isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

From what I'm seeing you're filling up the `$connectionString` variable with this value: `"\WindowsAzure\Blob\Internal\IBlob"` (even though it's commented - so probably you're passing it from somewhere else). If that's the case you'll need to change it.

The connection string should be a reference to your storage account containing the protocol, the name of the account and the key (you can find the name and the key in the portal):

```
$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=jeroensaccount;AccountKey=fjmezfjmIOFJEZIOPAFJAZOPIFJAIMO"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what I see, that should make a lot more sense, but I'm still getting the http 500 error. Hope you see something else that can cause the problem. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Hi Sandrino, I narrowed down the search and came to a $httpClient variable that gives the error. I edited my post and hope you'll find something usefull in there.